# Working with UTF-8 encoded TCL files on windows

Tags: windows, utf-8, character-encoding, tcl, tk-toolkit

We try to convert the source files of a TCL/TK application to UTF-8, because this is the default charset of the plattforms we use for development (Linux and OSX).

Our problem is now that windows uses "cp1252" as system encoding, and because of this displays labels and buttons with (for example) german umlauts wrong.
The only solution we found yet would be to add "-encoding UTF-8" to all "wish" calls and "source" commands.

(There is also "encoding system UTF-8", but the documentation says that you shouldn't use it because of problems with system calls)

Is there a way to tell TCL that it should use UTF-8 as default encoding for all source files, or maybe another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested in the TCL chat:

Create and use your own versions of "open" und "source" (like "my_open" and "my_source") which then call the original commands with "-encoding utf-8"